# Server.MapPath with ~

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the path.
Not sure if it should be:

```
    string driveLetter =  Server.MapPath("~/Docs/");
```

or

```
    string driveLetter =  Server.MapPath("~/Docs");
```

Comment: When you tried it, what was the output of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want physical file path of Docs folder then just use

```
string driveLetter =  Server.MapPath("~/Docs");
```